# How to specify that WiFi or 3G is required?

Tags: ios, network-programming

First of all, I know I can use `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` to specify that my app needs WiFi.

But in fact, my app works fine with both WiFi or 3G. How can I express such a network requirement? It there any `Info.plist` key for this? Or is testing myself with `Reachability` the only way to go?

Answer (score 3):

What exactly are you trying to do? If all you need is network access, then you don't have to do anything at all to make it work. Reachability can be useful, because it lets you quickly test if the network is available before attempting to connect anywhere, but that's only useful if you need to know if there is a network before even attempting to use it. Under normal circumstances, you can just attempt to use the network, and gracefully handle any errors that may occur.

Comment: I want a nice prompt for users if neither WiFi nor 3G is available. A more general key than `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` would make this very simple.

Comment: @an0: If you try to use the network, and get an error, you can then display a nice error message to the user. `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` only exists for apps that require the wifi to remain powered even when the device is locked. That concept doesn't apply to the 3G radio, since the phone needs to act like a phone even while locked and therefore maintains the 3G connection.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be use `SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback` (which gets called whenever the status of the network changes) and then throw an error if there's no WiFi or 3G connection.

b.t.w., all the keys UIKit supports in Info.plist can be seen at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Comment: Note that you shouldn't check reachability and throw an error in lieu of just attempting a network connection. Reachability's information may be stale, and it saves you absolutely nothing by using it instead of just attempting a connection. However, if you do attempt a connection and then get an error, then it may be useful to listen to Reachability's notification to find out when the network is back (if you want to automatically retry, or otherwise display network status to the user).